# Can't use .NET's JavaScriptSerializer in Unity and MonoDevelop on MacOS

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to use .NET's `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to read a JSON file into a Dictionary in Unity with MonoDevelop on MacOS.

So far I've added the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly to MonoDevelop which makes it build the "Assembly-CSharp" project fine.

But when I go back to Unity, it still shows the error: *error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Web' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?*

Then I read on the web that adding the DLL anywhere into the assets folder would do, so I found some versions of  the file `System.Web.Extensions.dll` inside MonoDevelop's path, they are in: `/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Extensions`

There are 3 folders with different versions of the file: `1.0.61025.0__31bf3856ad364e35`, `3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35` and `4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35`

Tried all of them, but none works, Unity gives this error:

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:InternalGetType (System.Reflection.Module,string,bool,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType (System.String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.GetTypeInAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.LookupTypeReflection (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc, Boolean must_be_unique) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.LookupTypeReflection (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc, Boolean must_be_unique) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Namespace.LookupType (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Namespace.Lookup (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeManager.CoreLookupType (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String ns_name, System.String name, Kind type_kind, Boolean required) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeManager.InitCoreTypes (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

So, what now?

Comment: Volunteer to add this assembly to the open source Mono project?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses an old version of Mono that does not support .NET 4. I believe they also remove System.Web.dll to slim it down, since System.Web mostly contains ASP.NET which isn't really relevant to game developers.

You might be able to copy over Mono's dlls, however make sure you use v2.0 of System.Web.dll and v3.5 of System.Web.Extensions.dll.

Alternatively you might try JSON.NET.

Comment: Cool thanks! So, any Unity-Mono built-in way to get data from a file which doesn't involve the classical fopen fseek way? maybe XML or something structured like that. Even regular .ini file parsing would do.

Comment: Not sure since I don't know exactly what Unity removes or adds. For XML, I would assume you have access to System.Xml.dll and System.Xml.Linq.dll, or for ini-like parsing you can use System.IO classes directly, particularly the simple System.IO.File.ReadAllLines.

Answer (score 0):

Try Serializing your data, `BinaryFormatter` + `MemoryStream` + `TextAsset`

`BinaryFormatter` + `MemoryStream`: object <==> byte[]

`TextAsset.bytes` is used for binary data file.