# how to deserialize json with arbitrary string keys using JsonUtility(unity c#)?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, unity-game-engine, deserialization

Unity, c#, use JsonUtility.
Say I have a json string as follows:

```
{
    "1,1":"dd",
    "2,1":"abc",
    "2,2":"123"
}
```

The amount and content of keys are arbitrary. How can I deserialize this json and transfer to my own class using JsonUtility.FromJson<>()?

If the keys are fixed, then I know you can make a class with variables with the name of the keys. What to do if keys are arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deserialize data with an arbitrary key is to use a data type which can hold an arbitrary key, such as a dictionary.

In c# it would be as below, but I think JsonUtility should be able to do about the same.

```
var input = "{\"1,1\":\"dd\",\"2,1\":\"abc\",\"2,2\":\"123\"}";
var dictionary = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(input);
```

This would result in:

```
{[1,1, dd]}
{[2,1, abc]}
{[2,2, 123]}
```

Keep in mind this will only work if you can guarantee unique keys in the json dataset.

Once you have the data deserialized you could always convert it to a different type/class if needed.

Comment: I tried using System.Web etc. but in unit it can't find the namespace.  Seems not supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032101/cant-use-nets-javascriptserializer-in-unity-and-monodevelop-on-macos

Comment: @ArtS: The Dictionary class is found in the System.Collections.Generic namespace. The System.Web.Scripts.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer class was only used with the example of deserialization, but I'd thought you'd take the JsonUtility one.

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't found a way to do this. Workaround: change the JSON structure to avoid dictionary with arbitrary keys.
The dictionary mentioned in the question can be changed into:

```
[
    {"key":"1,1","value":"dd"},
    {"key":"2,1","value":"abc"},
    {"key":"2,2","value":"123"}
]
```