# Convert JSON string to C# object without declaring class to deserialize into

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string. I want to cast the string to object **without declaring a class before**. This code will work if there's the object. but the problem is I can't use the result like a dictionary.

JSON String sample:

> {"code":200,"detail":"your request is accepted","data":[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"Bee"}]}

The code:

```
void callback(string response)
{
   var obj = response as object; // It's not error but this may can't cast to object
   var level_1 = obj as Dictionary<string,object>;
   print(level_1["code"]); // This should print 200 at Console. 
                           // but it doesn't this shows error "Value cannot be null."
                           // so the obj variable should be cast to empty object.
"
}
```

I tried to find, but I found only casting the string to **declared class** such as:

```
[Serializable]
public MyClass()
{
   public code;
}
var obj = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClass>(Json);
```

Is there a way to convert an arbitrary JSON string into an object without declaring a class with all the fields it has?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "raw" object, but a string is a string. Using standard JSON deserializer JSON.Net, you can *deserialize* to a `dynamic`, to `JObject`, or to a `Dictionary` and are not limited to a compile-time class definition.

Comment: I don't think `JsonUtility.FromJson()` can deserialize to a dictionary, see [how to deserialize json with arbitrary string keys using JsonUtility(unity c#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40204522) and [Is it possible to deserialize a dictionary in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38982324).  If you could switch to a different serializer such as [tag:json.net] it would be easy.  Can you do that?

Comment: Generally speaking, what you are attempting to do defeats the purpose of having a strongly typed language. I would recommend instead you create classes to represent what you are expecting to receive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/1092820) See part 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/1092820)

Comment: @crashmstr You should've posted that as the answer. Deserializing to dynamic would be the most appropriate answer but perhaps someone could document the downsides as well

Answer (score 1):

### Solution #1

Thank you guys for your helpful idea. Now with your all idea, I can figure it out.

```
using Newtonsoft;

void callback(string response)
{
   dynamic level_1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
   print("code: " + level_1.code); // The console now shows 200
}
```

Comment: Additional resources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object